# Recursion with global defined variable get more stacks than recursive function without a global defined variable. Why? (jumping into C++)

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I am working on learning C++ among other books with "Jumping into C++" from Alex Allain and am getting into recursion.
There is one program example to figure out how many recursions my computer can handle until a "stack overflow error" occurs or in my case a "Segmentation fault" appears.

I wrote a short program to test it on my own before I used the given example code and it showed
that my code can handle more than double the recursions than the given example code. My question: Why is that, since it is nearly the same pattern - a function calls itself and iterates an integer.

1. Why more than double as much recursions until the error appears? In my understanding the same amount of Stacks are used for both algorithms and they should use up more or less the same amount in my understanding of it.

And 2nd, why is there a segmentation error and not a stack overflow?

I really want to understand c++ programming and want to be able to write "inexpensive" programs that uses the bare amount of system resources really are necessary.

MY CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int i = 1;

void recurse ()
{

    i = i + 1;
    cout << "number: " << i << endl;

    recurse();
}

int main()
{
    recurse();
}
```

THE CODE EXAMPLE FROM THE BOOK:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void recurse(int count)
{
    cout << count << endl;
    recurse(count + 1);
}

int main()
{
    recurse(1);
}
```

My output:
[Output Screenshot of both examples on my system to see the difference i am
referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Lmb.png)

Used compiler Linux g++ -std=c++17 (Arch Linux)

Comment: Did you add any optimization flags?

Comment: No I didn't add any optimizations. Thanks for your answer btw. If I read through all the answers, i get the tendency. His point is "The stack is a fixed size, which means that you cannot have limitless recursion. At some point, there
won't be any more room for a new stack frame to be added onto the top of the stack—just like running
out of space to stack up another plate in your cabinet." And that was prooven but could have resulted in nothing at all.

My next question that comes up out of the answers, how can I avoid running out of stack - since it really is limited?

Comment: The stack is generally large enough to hold "enough" function calls, unless you do excessive recursion (which is probably a bad idea in terms of performance anyway). You can also run out of stack by allocating large objects on the stack (e.g. a lot of `int myArray[10000];` local variables). But generally speaking, it's not something to worry about if you aren't doing very extravagant things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both versions of the code have **undefined behavior**. A compiler can easily prove that the `recurse` function recurses endlessly, and that it will also eventually have an integer overflow.

The C++ standard explicitly says that there are no constraints on the behavior of a program with undefined behavior. You may get a stack overflow, a segmentation violation, your hard drive might be formatted, nuclear missiles might be launched, demons might come flying out of your nose, the program might do nothing, or (worst of all) it might accidentally do what you wanted.

As such, it is more or less pointless to test the limits of your system using a C++ program with undefined behavior.

See here for how two compilers transform your code under optimizations if you remove the output:
https://godbolt.org/z/Lqln9n

Notice how `clang` sees the undefined behavior and replaces it with a "do nothing and return". You won't get a crash on that compiler, the program will just do nothing! And MSVC optimizes the endless recursion into a trivial endless loop (`loop: jmp loop`). It will repeat that one instruction forever instead of getting the stack overflow mentioned in the warning.

With output in the mix, compilers might do different things again. But in every case, there is no meaningful answer you get from running the program, other than "the compiler decided to do it like that". You can inspect the generated assembly code (see above) to see *what* the compiler did and then use that to explain the behavior you see. But I must repeat that the given C++ code **has no defined behavior and might do anything**.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Bathsheba that this is a pretty silly and/or bad thing to do.

But to answer your question: The reason for why your code could handle more recursions than the book code, is that the book code had a local variable, which in turn meant that they used more stack-space per call then your code did. Look [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195385/understanding-stack-frame-of-function-call-in-c-c) for a bit of explanation of what a stack frame is - no need to understand it all, mostly just look at the pictures to get an idea.

However, this also highlights how silly an exercise this is: How many recursion calls your code can handle before it falls over with a crash, is dependent on a whole host of parameters - some you control, but also a lot you don't. So whatever number you wind up with do not really mean anything.

Not to mention that if your compiler has tail-call-recursion optimization enabled, then it will simply reuse the same stack frame for every recursive call, and then the answer is infinite (or integer overflow).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Hah, I didn't even consider that. But of course the compiler could be able to see that the count isn't actually used for anything and just optimize it away - along with everything else. Which just shows even further what a silly measurement this is. :)

Comment: I think this is a sensible, practical answer. Someone who understands the general principles of operating system design, but without in-depth knowledge; someone who understands the general purpose of a conventional stack, and heap; someone like that could be legitimately puzzled as to why using a global variable instead of a function parameter ends up running through many more recursive calls than otherwise. There's a practical value in this question, setting aside undefined behavior, compiler optimizations, et. al.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest explanation is that each invocation of `recurse(int count)` must have its own instance of `count` variable, whereas all calls to `recurse()` use a single global instance of `i`. In the former case, that private copy of `count` has to be stored somewhere, probably in the local stack frame.

However, this explanation is very fragile as your example is so simple that the compiler may well have figured that it could pass `count` in register and replace tail recursion with a simple loop. This is all really a subject of compiler optimization...

Comment: It is primarily fragile because there is undefined behavior. Your explanation is probably correct for some compiled binary, but there is **no guarantee whatsoever** that this explanation/situation remains true for arbitrary perturbations of compiler/code/platform etc.

Comment: @MaxLanghof agreed! However I thought that understanding how this code _might work_ could come handy for an inquiring mind. IMO, knowing how your code could get rendered to machine instructions is a plus.

Comment: I fully agree that knowing how your code might get rendered to machine instructions is a good idea. However, the way to do that is to inspect the actual machine code, not write and run programs with undefined behavior and then try to glean information from the ashes :)

Comment: Oh, reflecting on the ashes is a useful experience, come dump analysis time :) Though, as you've said, it's far from canonic way to study things.

Answer (score 0):

Burn the book.

You need something in `recurse` to *block* the recursion. Something like

```
if (count < 10){
    recurse(count + 1);
}
```

Technically the behaviour on your not doing something like that is *undefined* as eventually the `int` will overflow. It's the fact that you have undefined behaviour on all execution paths that means it's impossible to say much about the error: an aggressive compiler will compile your code to `int main(){}` as it's allowed to assume that undefined behaviour cannot happen. A compiler with run-of-the-mill optimisation settings may well unroll the recursion to an infinite loop.

With compiler optimisations suppressed, you'll hit upon a runtime constraint such as a stack overflow before the `int` limit is reached. That probably manifests itself as the segmentation fault you observe, or some other issuance from the C++ runtime library / operating system. The C++ standard does not specify the error that should emanate.

Comment: You're not really answering any of OP's questions: _Why more than double as much recursions until the error appears?_ and _why is there a segmentation error and not a stack overflow?_

Comment: @nada: Done my best with a revision - real issue is that the C++ standard doesn't specify the composition of the error (and the book's example is frankly shocking). I'll leave the answer up for the time being; will remove if the community shows it dislikes it.

Comment: Its a pdf, so.. ;)